# How to seed data and test one to many relationship with EF Core SQlite in memory?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

I am unit testing an EF Core MVC project using in memory Sqlite and have a one to many
relationship between the two tables below. Where ResourceRequest has an ICollection of
Resourcetags. How would I go about seeding data when adding a new Resourcetag in the test
method? Are there any contstraints for this using in memory testing?

```
    public DbSet<ResourceRequest>? Resources { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ResourceTags>? ResourceTags { get; set; }

     [TestMethod]
    public void AddResourceTagsSavesAResourceTagsViaContext()
    {
        using (var factory = new PrismContextFactory())
        { 
            // Arrange values
            Random rnd = new Random();
            var id = new byte[32];
            rnd.NextBytes(id);
            var text = "tagtext";
            string convertedId = Convert.ToBase64String(id);

            var reourceTag = new ResourceTags()
            {
                ResourceId = id,
                Tag = text,
                ResourceRequest = new ResourceRequest 
                { 
                   SubscriptionID = "",
                   TenantID = "",
                   Name = "",
                   ID = "",
                   ResourceGroup = ""
                },
            };

            // Get a context
            using (var context = factory.CreateContext())
            {
                context.Add(reourceTag);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            // Get another context using the same connection
            using (var context = factory.CreateContext())
            {
                var count = context.ResourceTags?.Count();
                Assert.AreEqual(1, count);

                var tagText = context.ResourceTags?.
                FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Tag == reourceTag.Tag);

                var tagId = context.ResourceTags?.
                FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.ResourceId == reourceTag.ResourceId);

                Assert.IsNotNull(tagText);
                Assert.IsNotNull(id);
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to test? This test method seems to only test EF Core logic and not really any of your own code.

Comment: I have a bunch of methods in a repository that do CRUD with a one to many relationship between two tables i.e a repository pattern which I tried to mock but ran into other issues. I need to unit test my methods and assert that they work using inmemory sqllite, if that's doable? I am new to testing btw.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

Comment: My question is can we use in-memory for relational stuff like one to many?